# UI issue for dropdown in firefox and Internet explorer

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I created a drop down as

```
<div class="col-lg-2 header-dropdown">
    <select (change)="onProjectChange($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let project of projectNameList" [value]="project.name" [selected]="project.selected">{{project.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My dropdown is looking like this in chrome

[image]

and in Firefox and internet explorer it is as follows

[image]

some white background is coming in arrow, how to fix this?

Comment: it's a browser behavior... If you want to have the same drop-down for all browser then go for JavaScript Custom Dropdown

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't use this,

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none; 
}

select::-ms-expand { display: none; } /*For IE */
```